# Blender fill fails?

Tags: vertices

I am trying to fill some edges, and it wont work propperly.
I hope someone could help me out.

[image: Without fill]
[image: With fill]

Comment: Are you attempting to get an Ngon or Quads? What's stopping you from just filling in the two ends?

Comment: I don't know what ngon or quads are, but when i fill the other ends, will it effect extruding the faces?

Comment: check if you have doubles or some unconnected vertex... a similar setup is: add a circle with 8 vertices, and try filling that. It should work.

Comment: Okay, but how do i connect vertex? I'm pretty new to blender.

Comment: @Mamori Tokonome I don't know how you got that 8-sided shape, but if you have some unconnected vertices, you can try this: select one of them (right-click), then select also the other vertex (shift+right-click)to which it should be connected, then press ALT+M and select "at last". If not clear, I will do an answer to better explain.

Comment: Select everything and press Ctrl+V for the vertex menu, then select "remove doubles"

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Ctrl+V is what I use and it works, check this for the documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html

Comment: You are right, didn't know about that menu, and it is not  even `Ctrl`+`W` it is just `W` > *Remove Doubles*, I'm a moron